# ChartJS not rendering lines according to x-axis data

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

Data:

```
const data={
  "labels": [
    0,  
    400,
      800,
      1200,
      1600,
      2000,
      2400,
      2800,
      3200,
      3600,
      4000
  ],
  "datasets": [
    {
      "axis": 'x',
      "label": "FFF",
      "borderColor": "Red",
      "backgroundColor": "Red",
      "data": [
          {
              "x": 2883,
              "y": 129
          },
          {
              "x": 3509,
              "y": 118
          },
          {
              "x": 3916,
              "y": 73
          }
      ]
  }
  ]
};
```

Chart:
[image]

I am providing both x & y axis values, the result should be like this for red line.
But for current config it rendering the line from start instead of specific point on x-axis.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `scatter chart` and `showline : true` option  instead of `line chart` for this result.

```
//your code

const data={
  "labels": [
    0,  
    400,
      800,
      1200,
      1600,
      2000,
      2400,
      2800,
      3200,
      3600,
      4000
  ],
  "datasets": [
    {
      "axis": 'x',
      "label": "FFF",
      "borderColor": "Red",
      "backgroundColor": "Red",
      "showLine": true,         //add this option to connect dots of scatterred points
      "data": [
          {
              "x": 2883,
              "y": 129
          },
          {
              "x": 3509,
              "y": 118
          },
          {
              "x": 3916,
              "y": 73
          }
      ]
  }
  ]
};

<Scatter data={data} />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using a line chart with default config.

By default a line chart uses a category scale and expects strings. In the dataset you specify an x, this x is the internal data format which for the catagory scale is not the value but the index.

The easyest approach would be to use a linear scale by setting `options.scales.x.type` to `'linear'`